How to formalize $P: \zeta \rightarrow \eta iff ...$ into a formula using First-Order language for set-theory?
In Ebbinghaus' "mathematical logic" Chapter X which is about decidability and enumerability, there is a definition:
$P:\zeta \rightarrow \eta$ iff P started with $\zeta$ eventually stops, having-in the course of the computation-given exactly one output, namely $\eta$
where P is a register program and $\zeta$ is the input.
I want to know how to formalize the definition into a formula using First-Order language for set-theory. Sure, I can formalize it as follows:
$P:\zeta \rightarrow \eta  \leftrightarrow Start(P,\zeta)\land EventuallyHalt(P) \land \eta \in Output(P)\land \exists !x x\in Output(P)$
But I want to reduce the predicates such as Start, EventuallyHalt to something more basic, even eliminate them at all. I think the key is to formalize the concept of an execution step of the program but do not know how.

You can see Computability and Logic (5th Ed) Ch.11, for a formalization in FOL of the Turing machine model.
For that model, the basic ingredients provided are the constant $0$ and two binary number predicates: $s(x,y)$ for the successor relation, and $<$.
In addition, some specific predicates are needed: for each of the
(nonhalted) states of the machine, numbered from $1$ to $k$ 1 to $k$,
a one-place predicate $\text Q_i$ denoting the set of $t \ge 0$ such that at the time numbered $t$ the machine is in the state numbered $i$.
Finally, tehre are two more two-place predicates: $\text @$ and $\text M$. The denotation of the former will be the set of pairs of integers $t \ge 0$ and $x$ such that at the time number $t$, the machine is at the square numbered $x$, and latter will denote the set of $t \ge 0$ and $x$ such that at time $t$, square $x$ is ‘marked’, that is, contains a stroke rather than a blank.
With this machinery in palce, and some useful abbreviations, the authors may write a sentence describing the configuration of the machine at time $0$ with input $n$:

$\text Q_00 \land \text @00 \land \text M 00 \land \text M 01 \land \ldots \text M 0n \land ∀x((x \ne 0 \land x \ne 1 \land \ldots \land x \ne (n-1)) \to \lnot \text M 0x)$.

A further convention is adopted: that of writing $\text M_e tx$ for "at time $t$, square $x$ contains symbol $e$" (where $e = 0$ means the blank, and $e = 1$ means the stroke).
Having produced a set $\Gamma$ of formal sentences "modelling" the Turing machine, the authors consider the sentence: "if you are in state $i$ and are scanning symbol $e$, then halt", that is formalized with:

$∃t∃x(\text Q_i t \land \text @ tx \land \text M_e tx)$.

